# java concurrency issue

Tags: java, concurrency

Why `n` sometimes equals 1 or 2

```
private static int n = 0;

private static Thread t1, t2;

private synchronized static void increment() {
    n++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            increment();
        }
    });

    t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            t1.start();
            increment();
        }
    });

    t2.start();

    try {
        t2.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Shouldn't the increment method only allow one thread to execute it at any given moment?

Maybe it is the debugger, it seems that when I run it normally I always get 2 but when i debug the code it some times return 1.

Comment: It looks like because you have static Thread instances, I suggest you stop making everything static. Also, don't call `t1.start();` in the `t2` run method.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - What will be the impact of `static` thread instances?. even if the thread instances weren't static, he would still end up with the same *unpredictable* behaviour . right?

Comment: @TheLostMind It isn't just the static Thread instances, I was observing that everything is static. Also, why have them? That is why not declare them in the `main` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does, however it could happen in either order. You only wait for `t2` to finish but not for `t1` to finish.

Wait for `t1` as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static int n = 0; 

private static Thread t1, t2;

private synchronized static void increment() {  // Lock will be on the "class" Object
    n++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            increment();
        }
    });

    t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            t1.start();           
// t1 starts after t2. Now, t1's increment might also be called or t2's increment() might also be called. If t2 calls increment(), then the join() method below (you are joining the in the main thread) will be completed and "n" will be printed (if t1 is not getting appropriate time of execution..)
            increment();
        }
    });

    t2.start();           // t2 starts first

    try {
        t2.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(n); // increment() might not have been called by t1
}
```

There is no guarantee that one thread would execute before another (even with synchronized condition..). So, you can `join` on both t1 and t2 . This will ensure you will always get output as 2.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if the `increment` invocation in the `run` method of `t2` takes place before the `increment` method of `t1` is invoked in `t1`'s `run` method, then `n` is locked and by the time `t2` ends, `t1` might still be running, but you're printing out `n` incremented by `t2` before `t1`'s increment is over.

To clarify:

- `t2` starts
- `t2` spawns `t1`
- `t2` invokes `increment` before `t1` has a chance to
- `n` is locked for the duration of `t2`'s `increment`
- main `Thread` joins `t2` before `t1` has a chance to `increment`
- main `Thread` prints `n` before `t1` has a chance to `increment`